# Visual Studio 2015: Omitting the <head> element in a HTML5 document

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a masterpage in VS2015 and would like to omit the `<head>` element from a cshtml document... Then VS warns me that the element 'title' can't be nested inside 'html' element:
[image]

However [W3Schools by ex](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp), informs us: 
[image]

Is there a way to "update" VS warnings to the new HTML5 standards?

Comment: This isn't even new to HTML5. It's been the standard since the *very beginning* of HTML - over 20 years now. Visual Studio seems to be confusing HTML with XHTML - where explicit tags are indeed required for html, head and body.

Comment: as for W3.org, the only place where a "title" could be found, is the "head" element: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element

Comment: Yes. The head element is there even when you omit the <head> tag. This has been the case since the beginning.

Comment: If you omit it the `head`, it will be the browser that will add it...